# Adding Raw Query Parameters to SolrQuery requests

Tags: php, solr

I'm using [SolrClient](http://php.net/manual/en/solrclient.query.php) with [SolrQuery](http://php.net/manual/en/class.solrquery.php) object, but I need to add RawQueryParameters to it:
[image]

How is this done? I'm fairly new to Solr requests and I could not find such option in the documentation.

So far I have this:

```
$SolrQuery = new \SolrQuery();
$SolrQuery->setStart($this->offset);
$SolrQuery->setRows($this->limit);
$SolrQuery->setQuery($request);
$SolrQuery->addField('*')->addField('units:[subquery]');
$SolrQuery->addParam('units.q', '{!terms%20f=id%20v=$row.unit_ids}');
```

When running `toString()` on this object, I get:

```
start=0&rows=2147483647&q=type:address&fl=*,units:[subquery]&units.q={!terms%20f=id%20v=$row.unit_ids}
```

what is the correct query. This works fine in CLI, but gives exception when executed in PHP as `$queryResponse = $SolrClient->query($SolrQuery);`:

```
Exception: while invoking units:[subquery] on doc=SolrDocument{id=stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS
```

*EDIT: Solution was to use `addParam()` without urlcoded request. Spaces go through just fine!*

Comment: `setParam` and `addParam` from `SolrModifiableParams` should do what you want - how are you using them? Have you checked the Solr log on the server side to see if anything is included at all? (i.e. could it be an escape issue?)

Comment: Hmm, do you know if there is an option to print out the final query the script is about to execute?

Comment: I'd watch the Solr log instead - it'll tell you exactly what query it received as long as you set the log level to `INFO`. It's available under 'Logging' in the Admin interface. For the Query object you can try calling `->toString()` and `var_dump` the result.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thank you, `toString()` worked and it does create the correct query. I tried it also from cli and it works fine, but when executing in PHP it gives me that exception. Are there maybe some parameters I need to add for the `$queryResponse = $SolrClient->query($SolrQuery);` request? Maybe even a different execute request?

Comment: First check the Solr log to see if the exception is generated from the Solr side or the PHP side (the extension) - that'll tell you where to check next. This might be an issue in how SolrClient attempts to parse the field list response, but confirm that Solr itself isn't generating an exception first (i.e. because of escaping in SolrClient, etc.)

Comment: I can't easily get to Solr logs currently as the requests go to a remote server, but I did carefully compare the parameters. Turns out I use `{!terms%20f=id%20v=$row.unit_ids}`, but I don't need to have it coded: `{!terms f=id v=$row.unit_ids}` works like a charm. If you can put up a short answer, I'd gladly accept it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the active parameters by calling `->toString()` on the `SolrQuery` object - since `SolrQuery` inherits from `SolrModifiableParams`, you can call `addParam` directly on the query object to add custom parameters. This lets you add any parameter you want to the request. Be careful to add the parameter verbatim, since SolrQuery should handle necessary escaping for you.

If you still see an error, you can check the logging on the Solr server (under Admin -> Logging). If the log level is set to `INFO`, Solr will log all requests so you can see what Solr actually got. Any exceptions should also be present in this log if they're generated on the Solr side.

The Solr extension will usually throw exceptions as the class `SolrClientException`, which can be useful to determine the source of the error. A [list of exception messages are also available in the extension source](https://github.com/php/pecl-search_engine-solr/blob/a00cea3f926d23fa993e78c36d6085a4a83ee05a/src/php5/solr_constants.h) if you need to debug further.